# How can I find the relative minimum and maximum point as $f(x)$ is equal to zero?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can I find the relative minimum and maximum points of $f(x)=x^3-\frac{3}{2}x^2$.

This is what I found so far:
\begin{align*}
 f(x)&=x^3-\frac{3}{2}x^2 
\\ f'(x)&= 3x^2-3x 
\\ f''(x)&=6x-3
\end{align*}

As the critical points are $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second derivative test since $f’’(0)<0$ and $f’’(1)$ is greater than $0$ which means that $0$ is a local maximum and $1$ is a local minimum.